# JavaScript event.preventDefault() with other arguements

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, preventdefault

I have this call to a function, which I want to pass the parameter btnSubmit:

```
$(btnSubmit).click( validate(btnSubmit, event) );
```

I want to first prevent the form from submitting and then validate. However, it submits anyway. It works if I don't pass btnSubmit in, but I would like to do that.

```
function validate (btnSubmit, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You'll need the basics of any event handler, an anonymous function -> `$(btnSubmit).click(function(event) { validate(btnSubmit, event) });`

Comment: Why not create `validate` as though it was a typical event handler where the bound element is referenced as `this`. Then it's just `$(btnSubmit).click(validate)`.

Comment: What do you think the execution order is for `foo(bar())`? Is `foo` or `bar` executed first?

Comment: @adeneo Thank you! If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @squint I might add more arguements to this in the future, so I feel like it's best to leave that variable for now.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not sure what foo and bar are representing here.

Comment: They are two functions.

Comment: Jordan Carter Felix Kling is trying to teach you something with this question/ understand whats your understanding

Comment: @NetaMeta I understand but at the moment I'm just trying to imagine a real example of what foo(bar()) would be, like what the syntax would be for real functions.

Comment: @FelixKling ok, so assuming it's like this: function foo(){ bar();}, we need to first call foo or else nothing would even happen. Once we call foo, bar will happen....am I understanding what you're asking? Are you saying "bar()" is an arguement for foo? I never thought of calling functions as an arguement before.

Comment: jordan you have copied his example wrong, `foo(bar())` not `foo(){ bar();}` these are 2 complete different operations

Comment: @NetaMeta Ok, so foo is defined as a function elsewhere already? That would mean we're calling foo, but we're passing bar as an arguement, but we're actually calling bar...this is strange to me because I don't think I've ever done that before, and I'm not sure why I would do it. To answer the question though, I *think* bar would come first, because functions get called as soon as you add those parentheses.

Comment: Here is a real example: `function getGreeting(name) { return 'Hi ' + name; }; console.log(getGreeting('Jordan'));`. I really doubt that you have never passed the return value of a function to another function :). But you are right, `bar` would be called first and the return value is passed to `foo`. That's the exactly what happens in your case (which is why your code is wrong): `$(...).click( validate(...) );` This calls `validate` immediately and passes its *return value* (which is `undefined`)  to `.click`. It does *not* pass the function `validate` to `.click` to be called later.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok I think I get it...but how is the anonymous function preventing a return value from getting stored in click now? Is it because it gets stored in the function, and since it's a function JavaScript knows to just execute it rather than store it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're doing:

```
$(btnSubmit).click( validate(btnSubmit, event) );
```

you're immediately calling the `validate` function and you're passing its returned value as a callback for `$(btnSubmit).click()`. Since that function doesn't return anything, no event handler is actually created.

You have two possible solutations:

1. As squint suggested, change the `validate` function to use `this` instead of `btnSubmit` and have `event` as the first argument:

   ```
   function validate (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
   ```

   Then assign the event handler like that:

   ```
   $(btnSubmit).click(validate);
   ```
2. Use an anonymous function that will pass the `btnSubmit` and `event` to `validate`:

   ```
   $(btnSubmit).click(function(event) {
     validate(btnSubmit, event)
   });
   ```